# Are Layer extensions supported in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro-sdk

Can I store some custom information about layer, project, etc?

For instance, featurelayer has no unique ID(I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like that) I want to add unique ID to each layer and store this information in aprx project file.

Can I do it using ArcGIS Pro SDK or any other way?